# Have hotels been re-established in Kedarnath, India after the floods?

Tags: india, hotels, event-based-effects, himalayas

Have hotels been established in kedarnath? That is, if I go there, will I have to say at tents or hotels gave come up? Same applies for Gaurikund. I have heard, that being on shore of Mandakini, most of hotels have been washed away. Have new ones come up in place of them?

Comment: Couple of hotels are functional while many are being re-constructed. Life is coming back to its pace there.

Comment: @Tal but I heard that people need to stay in tents nowadays. Can you give an official source?

Answer (score 1):

According to Booking.com, Hostelworld.com and Tripadvisor, the closest proper hotel to Kedarnath is [Shivalik Valley Resorts](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g1162521-d3650615-Reviews-Shivalik_Valley_Resorts-Kedarnath_Uttarakhand.html), which is approximately 19km away on foot. Tripadvisor reviews confirm that it's a good starting point for a trek to Kedarnath:

> We had a wonderful experience here. Slept well, ate well and felt fully ready to make the **climb to Kedarnath**! Hot showers after the hike felt phenomenal! I would definitely recommend staying at this hotel and would stay here again in the future.